# How to disable .text relocation in OS X?

Tags: c, macos, clang, relocation

I'm trying to get the return address by `__builtin_return_address()` in OS X:

```
/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    printf("return address: %p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));
}

int main() {
    foo();
}

bash-3.2$ clang foo.c
bash-3.2$ nm a.out
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
0000000100000f40 T _foo
0000000100000f70 T _main
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

However, it does not return the address I want.

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out
return address: 0x10c25cf79
bash-3.2$ atos -o a.out 0x10c25cf79
0x10c25cf79
```

It works well in LLDB though.

```
bash-3.2$ lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 77500 launched: '/private/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
return address: 0x100000f79
Process 77500 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000) 
(lldb) q
bash-3.2$ atos -o a.out 0x100000f79
main (in a.out) + 9
```

What's going on and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm sure this is related to the [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) security feature found on many modern OS implementations. The memory page size on OS X (Darwin) is 4KiB (4096 bytes), which offsets your addressing by `49756` pages, i.e., 0xC25C000. I believe this is the same page size for x86[-64] on Linux too. Not sure about the other BSDs, etc. My understanding is that LLDB disables ASLR - presumably because it makes debugging easier with repeated executions. Perhaps you can disable ASLR for normal execution...

Comment: @BrettHale It worked when I disabled ASLR. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BrettHale answered in the comment. This is caused by ASLR.

Disabling ASLR by `-no_pie` option resolves this problem.

```
$ clang -Wl,-no_pie foo.c
$ ./a.out 
return address: 0x100000f79
```

Comment: I wasn't sure *how* to disable it, or if this is the only mechanism. You should feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks again, @BrettHale!